# Error 'Plugin-Version' of 'unspecified' for 'com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin@1544e09d' is not a valid version number. Ionic 6

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

when trying to build the project for android (ionic cordova build android --prod --release), I get the following error:
Error 'Plugin-Version' of 'unspecified' for 'com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin@fbc39d3' is not a valid version number

OneSignal Warning: Could not get AGP plugin version

** I use cordova, I am stuck on that error as no material or explanations are coming to solve it
Ionic CLI         : 6.13.1
Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0

Comment: Are able to solve this issue ? i am getting the same error

Comment: +1 I'm also getting the same error. Tracking this issue on GH : https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/709

Answer (score 0):

Both lines are from [OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin) and indicate it could not find the version of the AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) in your project.

```
Error 'Plugin-Version' of 'unspecified' for 'com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin@fbc39d3' is not a valid version number

OneSignal Warning: Could not get AGP plugin version
```

This [Error](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/blob/0.13.4/src/main/groovy/com/onesignal/androidsdk/GradleProjectPlugin.groovy#L389) and [Warning](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/blob/0.13.4/src/main/groovy/com/onesignal/androidsdk/GradleProjectPlugin.groovy#L338-L345) messages will not cause a build failure. The AGP version detection is only used enable [AGP 2.x.x fall back logic](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/blob/0.13.4/src/main/groovy/com/onesignal/androidsdk/GradleProjectPlugin.groovy#L332-L334), if the version isn't found it assumes you are using AGP 3+.  AGP 3 was first added in [Cordova Android 7.0.0](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html) so as long as you are using this version or newer this won't cause any side effects either.

Until OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin improves this version detection you can safely ignore these two messages from it.